# How can I copy my application by having copy protection?

Tags: android

I need to protect my application against copy protection. I saw some apps in market that are unable to extract using any backup applications in my android device.

How can I make my application too against copy?

Comment: You should use Google Licensing Service,  as Copy Protection will deprecated soon

Comment: They have been saying it will be deprecated forever now, Licensing Service comes with its own problems mainly the fact that you need to connect to the net to check the lincense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is currently being deprecated as a way of copy-protecting your app. It's an option you can choose before publishing your app in the Developer's console. A much better and safer approach is to use [The License Verification Library.](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a check box you tick when you are publishing your app. I'm pretty sure that it's near the end of the page, after the payment details section.